# Youtube video only play for 50 seconds to a minute and a half

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, youtube

When i go to watch a Youtube video it will play for 50 seconds to a minute and a half. Why is it doing this? I have cleared my cookies and all other browsing history and re installed chrome and it still doing this.

Comment: It is not my internet connection. As there is more video buffered out before it stops

Comment: I had the same problem. For me it was Google's own **Chrome Toolbox extension** who was the culprit. If you have it installed try disabling it.

Comment: Is there enough space on the disk where it stores the temporary files?

Comment: Wow it was "Chrome Toolbox extension". But is there a way to have it enabled and videos still play. Because i really want tab scrolling

Comment: Nope, none of the settings (and changing them) in Chrome Toolbox seems to change the fact that it causes the freezing of Youtube after 1-1,5 minutes. I think we need to wait for an update from Google. Also the Chrome Toolbox update is from May so it must be something in the new version of Chrome (or YouTube) because it started just last week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll add this as an answer because it turned out to be the cause:

---

The problem is that since the first week of October 2013 YouTube freezes its playback after 1 to 1,5 minute. I found that the most likely cause of this freezing is Google's own **Chrome Toolbox extension** (it was for me). When disabling this extension the playback of YouTube continues as normal.

I have also found that none of the settings in the extension have any influence on this disruption. Because the last update of the Chrome Toolbox extension (1.0.32) is of May 2013 the cause has to be found in a new Chrome update or YouTube. As of half September Google has made a lot of changes to YouTube (for example removing the old subscription box). Also as of last week my videos start muted (needing to adjust the volume slider to get audio) So maybe Google is tweaking YouTube with some bugs as a result.

We need to wait for a fix from Google while keeping the Chrome Toolbox disabled until then.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hotfix:

Navigate to `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\fjccknnhdnkbanjilpjddjhmkghmachn\1.0.32_0\floating_bar.js`

Add two forward slashes before line 157, as so:

```
//.addEventListener('mouseout', hidden , false)
```

Commenting out this line removes the error.