# YouTube videos get stopped after playing 58 seconds

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I don't know why, but from few days I have been facing this problem. After playing for a certain length of time, mostly 58 seconds, videos are getting paused and they won't move further. I am using Google Chrome browser, and I have searched the internet for any solutions and none of them worked for me. My internet connection is of good speed.

Some videos stop at 58 seconds, some at 2.26 seconds. I have a Core i7 2nd generation laptop. I tried cleaning the temp folder, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think it's a Flash player bug -- I submitted a trouble report several days ago so hopefully it will be fixed in the next update.

Comment: What exactly is the problem ? Is the video closing ? Are you getting a colored screen (green) ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk no nothing. it just stops playing. no error messages no colored screen etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide any informations or screenshots on the exact error you are getting, the best solutions for you would be the following,

- Reinstall flash player to make sure it is not a flash problem.
- Try another web browser to see if you can reproduce the issue elsewhere.

Also, editing you question to explain exactly what happens with the page at that time will help us solve your issue.
How to remove flash in chrome :

1. Type "about:plugins" w/o the quotation in the navigation bar.
2. On the upper right u will see "Details" click it then find the word "flash", and you will see like this:

Flash - Version: 10.1.102.64
Shockwave Flash 10.1 r102
Name: Shockwave Flash
Description: Shockwave Flash 10.1 r102
Version: 10,1,102,64
Priority: 25
Location: C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32.dll
Disable
MIME types:
MIME type Description File extensions
application/x-shockwave-flash Adobe Flash movie
.swf
application/futuresplash FutureSplash movie
.spl

3. Copy the location above in the bold format.
4. Go to my documents, in the navigation bar paste the location.
   Note: only this for example: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\" except the word NPSWF32.dll above, to me it's NPSWF32.dll 'coz i'm using now the old version of flash player the latest flash player i think is different, but when u see the file .dll it has a description under it u will see like this: 10.1.102.64 Shockwave Flash 10.1 r102.
5. Delete that file you better do this: hold "Shift+Delete".
6. Your done! Restart your computer.
7. Open chrome type again "about:plugins" and if you did not see the word flash then you successfully deleted the latest version of flash player, if not do the same again.

Comment: OP is using Chrome, it has Flash Player built in.

Comment: there is no error displaying. after playing it just stops playing that video. while the buffering bar will be far from actual playing bar. think you understand what i said.

Comment: @gronostaj yes it has flash player built in.

Comment: You can still remove the extention in the browser,

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this solved yet? A few weeks ago i had exactly the same problem. ([Here](https://superuser.com/questions/655151/what-is-going-on-with-youtube/655209#655209) was a question of a user with my answer)

It turned out to be due to the **Chrome Toolbox extension** . After disabling that extension the problem went away.

There are no settings in this extension you can change to make it work so disabling it is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problems a few month ago, like other people in my area. It turned out to be a problem with my ISP, which got fixed after a few days.

Answer (score 0):

There have been several alternatives posted but no one has mentioned the HTML 5 alternative.

[You can activate the HTML 5 version of YouTube here.](http://youtube.com/html5)

Then, whenever possible, YouTube will use HTML 5 to stream videos as opposed to Flash. If your video is available in HTML 5 and it plays all the way through without stopping then you know for sure that it is a Flash issue.

On the other hand, if you continue to face issues then you may way to consider different paths of investigation i.e. problem with the browser, driver problems and so forth.